# Unity facebook plugin collision

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, plugins

In unity project with imported Facebook sdk 7.14.0 when I build for Android/iOS there is no such a trouble as I have when try build on Standalone.

So, I provide screenshot, and I hope there are people who solve that problem earlier.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Have you recently updated Facebook SDK? Were you using Facebook SDK previously on your project?

Comment: I got this project from previous programmers, and yes - they used this plugin. But I have no ability to get info from them. Version of plugin I use 7.14.0. But I see that on official web-site was update a 5 days ago to version 7.14.1

Comment: It seems that some dll from the previous SDK were not deleted correctly when importing the new version. I'd try to delete everything that is Facebook SDK related and reimport the newest version. The files might be conflicting.

Comment: The thing is, I didnt update plugin to last version so far. And the old version justhave two dll that have the same name, but they ij different folders.